# Reading CSV file data in PHP

Tags: php, csv, foreach

I'm trying to create a page which pulls infoprmation from a CSV file, using PHP.
It should then populate a product list with the information.

This is the CSV file: 
[image: CSV file image]

The code I have is as follows:

```
$file = file('data-example.csv');
$line = array("name", "id","price", "description");
foreach($file as $line) {   
    $csv = explode('//',$line);
    $item = $csv;
    print_r($item);
```

This is currently printing out the whole of the array. I'd like to know how I can access the individual nodes on the array, so that I could include them as variables within an HTML table.

Thanks
Ali

To amplify, and respond to the replies (thanks!):
This is the amended code, using `fgetcsv`:

```
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    echo($data[1][1]);        
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

This seems to work, but returns the column contents. This is the data (data.csv):

```
"Dandelion","30","13.99","Dandelion 30 "
"Daisy","40","20.99","Daisy 40 "
"Cress","27","10.99","Cress 27 "
"Coral","17","6.99","Coral 17 ",
"Honeysuckle","40","17.99","Honeysuckle 40 "
"Rose","27","9.99","Rose 27"
```

"
(there's a new line at dandelion, Daisy,Cress,Coral,Honeysuckle and Rose)

When I try `echo($data[1]);` it gets the whole column as described, i.e 30 40 27 17 40 27 but `echo($data[1][1]);` returns "342142", and `echo($data[1][1][1]);` creates an error.
I don't understand it as this is an array?

Thanks
Ali

Comment: Please post the actual text from the file, not a pic.

Comment: PHP has native function to read CSV.. made research?

Comment: Use thefgetcsv()  function which returns an array of rows of the csv file

Answer (score 0):

You should use native php functions to read csv files, such as [str_getcsv](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Something like:

```
$Data = str_getcsv($CsvString, "\n"); //parse the rows
foreach($Data as &$Row){ 
   $Row = str_getcsv($Row, ";"); //parse the items in rows 
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use [fgetcsv](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) that parses the line it reads for fields in CSV format and returns an array containing the fields read, i.e.:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```